# How to show a div tag based on the another div radio button?

Tags: html, angular

i am having the multiple components base component is welcome component and other is child component. inside the welcome component have the navigation component and others. based on the navigation selection i want to change the body component. what can i do?

**Welcome.component.html**

```
<div style="height: 140px;">
 <h1 class="col-md-3" style="text-align: center">Hi {{currentUser.name}}!
 </h1>
 <app-nav></app-nav>
</div>
<div>
 <app-home *ngIf="slideItem=='home'"></app-home>
 <app-blog *ngIf="slideItem=='blog'"></app-blog>
 <app-about *ngIf="slideItem=='about'"></app-about>
</div>
```

navigation.component.html

```
<nav class="slidemenu col-md-6">
<input type="radio"  [(ngModel)]="slideItem" value="home" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-1" class="slide-toggle" />
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="slideItem" value="edit" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-2" class="slide-toggle"/>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="slideItem" value="blog" name="slideItem" id="slide-item-4" class="slide-toggle"/>
</nav>
```

Comment: instead of ngIf and adding all the components at once, you can use the `<router-outlet>` for displaying your component based on the menu selection

Comment: do you have app routes defined in your app ?

Comment: yes, app routes and <router-outlet> used in app-component

Answer (score -1):

You can go for ui-router in angular js.

## index.html

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

## route.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/edit',
            templateUrl: 'partial-edit.html'
        });

});
```

## partial-home.html

same for blog and edit;

Comment: it's working for angular 4? also i am not having any js file

Comment: you need create a new js file. it will work fine for angular js 1

Comment: step by step approach in this link for routing https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router .

Comment: I think the user is looking for an angular4 answer and you have provided angularJS(1.x) answer

Comment: @VenkatLokeswar - i want angular 4 answer only